# Why PHPUnit tests run faster when the machine is disconnected from the internet?

Tags: php, performance, testing, connection, phpunit

I have noticed that when my laptop is connected to the internet my PHPUnit tests takes between ~90 sec ~200 sec to finish. But when I disconnect it from the internet it runs in less than 20 sec!! that makes me happy and sad at the same time!

In both cases all the tests are passing, I'm sure I'm mocking every request to external API's.

I'm using Laravel and MySQL for real data storage and in-memory sqlite for the tests environment. Also my development environment is all on running on Docker.

Is this something related to PHPUnit or to my code!! any one has an idea on what's going on. Thanks

**More Info**

The domain I'm using is `something.dev` and my API's uses `api.something.dev`. Every test makes at least one call to each API endpoint.

**DNS!**
If you think this is due to DNS lookup: I changed all the domain and subdomains to 127.0.0.1 just to test it, and it didn't helped the tests are still slow. Should this eliminate the possibility of DNS lookup!

In addition I tried mocking the DNS using [The PHPUnit Bridge](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/phpunit_bridge.html) with PHPUnit but I guess I couldn't make it work due to the lack of documentation, so I didn't knew what to pass as parameter to   `DnsMock::withMockedHosts([here!!])` after calling it from my `setUp()` function.

**Something else**
I think the problem is related to the data storage because the delay happens before and after querying the database, mostly to store data.

Comment: Try starting debugging with https://github.com/johnkary/phpunit-speedtrap to see specifically which unit tests are much slower. Maybe it shows something unexpected if your test suite is really big.

Comment: @Iskar knowing which tests are slow when internet is up, is not helpful, I have carefully monitored some tests execution and the time is so random and doesn't make any sense. Especially when I run the same tests offline nothing take more than 0.**** sec.

Comment: Seems that your code or unit tests make network requests (whether it's DNS lookups or something else). When you are not connected, the request fails quickly (does not wait for a response) and continues with the rest of the code. Those network requests don't fail the tests so they might be difficult to find but that's what you need to figure out. You could look at the network traffic to see what exactly is being sent when you are connected to the internet.

Comment: I am agree with @swbandit. You could use `Wireshark` and monitor your network traffic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wow that wasn't expected. Turns out my tests are slow because of the `image()` function provided by the PHP [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) package `$faker->image()`.

I was using it in one of my factories to prepare a fake Image for the DB, I didn't know it's literally downloading images and storing them in folder like this `/private/var/folders/51/5ybn3kjn8f332jfrsx7nmam00000gn/T/`.

I was able to find that by monitoring what the PHP process is doing while the test is running, to find out it has an open .jpg file in that directory, so I looked in my code anything related to images and discovered that, after about 6 hours of debugging. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Never use `$faker->image('storage/app',640,480, null, false)` in factory
: it will be time consuming.

Transform

```
$factory->define(Model::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'description' => $faker->text,
        'image' => $faker->image('storage/app',640,480, null, false),
    ];
});
```

into

```
$factory->define(Model::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'description' => $faker->text,
        'image' => 'test.png',
    ];
});
```